# Localhost: Wordpress nmedia user uploader plugin File upload error

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, xampp, localhost, filesize

On my localhost (XAMPP) environment I am using Wordpress plugin called nMedia User Uploader and getting below error while uploading file

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite/site-content/uploads/articles/user_uploads/jack_artist/Untitled-1.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\plugs\nmedia-user-file-uploader\nm_fileuploader.php on line 214
```

I tried to check with `var_dump($dt);` but cant understand what is wrong here.

```
array(6) { ["fileName"]=> string(14) "Untitled-1.jpg" ["fileDescription"]=> string(0) "" ["userID"]=> int(3) ["fileType"]=> string(4) ".jpg" ["fileSize"]=> bool(false) ["fileUploadedOn"]=> string(19) "2012-08-25 19:20:37" }
```

Here is the $dt array

```
$dt = array(    'fileName'          => nmFileUploader::$file_name,
                'fileDescription'   => nmFileUploader::$desc,
                'userID'            => $user_id,
                'fileType'          => nmFileUploader::$file_type,
                'fileSize'          => filesize($filePath),
                'fileUploadedOn'    => current_time('mysql')
             );
```

So is this issue with localhost xampp and will work on live server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is due to file permission setting on localhost, please check this on live or Linux based environment where directory permissions set to 775.

Comment: It is against the rules to add signatures/advertisements to your posts. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @Najeeb Ahmad, You are right. I wrote function to block wp-admin url and that blocks this plugin to upload media file. But is it possible to make it works if even I block wp-admin access to user?